# Why is "uses" in "Peter is uses a dictionary" wrong?

Tags: tense

> 1. Peter is **uses** a dictionary.
> 2. Peter is **using** a dictionary.

Could someone help explain why "uses" is wrong? I know that "using" is the right one and "uses" is wrong but I couldn't find the reason or the supporting grammatical rules that explain why it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed one actual verb per clause -- only one word carries the tense.  'Is' and 'uses' are both verbs (present tense).  'Using' is a participle which can be used with a form of 'be' such as 'is' (present tense) to form the progressive aspect.  'Uses' would have to be used alone, forming the habitual present tense.

Comment: *Peter uses and abuses a dictionary.* That is two "actual verbs" in one clause. So, something in your explanation needs to be expanded on.

Comment: That is two coordinated clauses.  If we expand every detail then the gist is lost.